# Узнать номер (или пронумировать) ячейки в виде Int tableView Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
Для последующего фетча данных по ключу из базы данных, надо пронумеровать ячейки tableView, что бы знать какой ключ забирать из массива ключей! Если кто-то знает простой способ как по выбранной ячейке совершить легкий фетч из бд FireBase буду признателен!

Comment: у каждой ячейки есть номер (IndexPath)

Comment: Я так понимаю он начинается с 0? То есть 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...?

Comment: он состоит из двух компонентов - indexPath.section и indexPath.row. каждый начинается с 0

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался!

Answer (score 1):

у каждой ячейки есть номер (IndexPath), он состоит из двух компонентов - indexPath.section и indexPath.row. каждый начинается с 0